# limit proof, epsilon delta

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

I am trying to prove a result I need in a proof, which is the following. Say I have two real values a,b and I can get the one as close to the other as I want |a-b|<ε then I want to prove I can get 1/a 1/b as close as Ι want to the other. |1/a - 1/b|<ε'.

a=a(y),b is a constant (it's part of a limit proof for the inverse function derivative)

I've proven so far  |1/a - 1/b|=|(a-b)/ab| < ε/|ab| Now as ε gets smaller ab approaches a constant value b^2 so I can make |1/a - 1/b| as small as I want.
How do I make the last argument rigorous?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are close to  $0$ (hence also to each other) then $\frac 1 a$ and $\frac  1b$ need not be close to each other.

Comment: Ok I get it. But (I may be wrong) only if you move both values close to zero this weird behavior happens. If b is a fixed number (as I mentioned above) and a gets close to it then 1/a gets close to 1/b.Why doesn't my last argument in the post work? It looks very convincing from a first view. Anyway, thanks for the answer.